# "Scroll Down" JavaScript Function Not Scrolling To Correct Location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a landing page that has a "scroll down" feature. The code for this feature was taken from [this codepen example](https://codepen.io/nxworld/pen/OyRrGy) (scroll down button #5).

My landing page looks like this:

[image]

Right now, when you click on "scroll", you're immediately take down to this point (without a smooth transition):

[image]

when you should be taken all the way down to this point (with a smooth transition + where the header touches the top of the window/screen):

[image]

So what do I need to fix in my JavaScript to make it scroll to the correct point? Here is what I have:

```
//javascript functions
(function ($, root, undefined) {    
$(function () { 
    'use strict';       
    // DOM ready, take it away      
}); 
})(jQuery, this);

//scroll down function
(function($) {
$('a[href*=#]').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log( $(".container").offset().top)
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({       
        scrollTop: $("#menu-main").offset().top - 6}, 1700);
    //$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 
$($(this).attr('href')).offset().top}, 500, 'linear');
});
})(jQuery);
```

I've tried adjusting the numbers in this line: `scrollTop: $("#menu-main").offset().top - 6}, 1700);`, 6 and 1700 with no effect.

Also tried uncommenting the last line and changing 500 to other numbers with no effect.

This is the HTML for the front page including the Nav Menu (the header):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>The Bullshit Collection</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <?php wp_head();?>
</head>
<body>
<!--start container-->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="/wp-content/themes/TheBullshitCollection/Images/white-background.jpg">
<div class="welcome-page-div">
<h3>Welcome</h3>
</div>

<div class="welcome-page-div">
<h3>To the Bullshit Collection</h3>
</div>

<section id="section5" class="demo">
    <a href="#section5"><span></span>Scroll</a>
</section>
</div>

<div id="menu-main" class="header-background">
<!--<div class="cursive"><a href="http://thebullshitcollection/home/">The Bullshit Collection</a></div> -->
<!--grabs first menu available-->
<!-- <div class="menu-main-navigation-container"> -->
    <center>
    <ul id="menu-main-navigation" class="menu container-1">
        <li id="menu-item-49" class=" cursive menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-50"><a id="logo" href="http://thebullshitcollection/">The Bullshit Collection</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-50"><a href="http://thebullshitcollection/">Home</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-51"><a href="http://thebullshitcollection/about/">About</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-52"><a href="http://thebullshitcollection/drawings/">Drawings</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-54" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-54"><a href="http://thebullshitcollection/photography/">Photography</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-55" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-55"><a href="http://thebullshitcollection/store/">Store</a></li>
    </ul>
    </center>
<!--</div> -->
</div>

<div id="stickyalias"></div>
```

It's hard to create a JSFiddle for this because it's a WordPress site and I'm using `<?php wp_head();?>` to get the header, which is where the Nav Menu is located. Let me know how else I can help, thanks!

**EDIT**: This is a pretty good example of what I'm trying to replicate: http://yoyomoi.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code that worked for scrolling down:

```
//scroll down
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('#section5').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#menu-main").position().top
    }, 2000);
    });
});
```

2000 controls the speed...lower number is faster, higher number is slower. Needed "#section5" in the first set of parentheses, this is the starting point. #menu-main is the end point. If anyone understands the rest of the code please explain.

Answer (score 1):

Ur id of scroll is same as it's target ?

```
<section id="section5" class="demo">
    <a href="#section5"><span></span>Scroll</a>
</section>
```

this is what you wrote
Let me explain how this works

`<a href ="#something"></a>`
 where `something = "name of id"` you wanna scroll to
so the section itself has `id="section5"` this means it is targeting itself which will take the scroll button to top which is not what we want

yes so.....let's change it's `id` to something relevant

```
<section id="scrollButton" class="demo"> 
<a href="#section5"><span></span>Scroll</a> 
</section>
```

Where we wanna scroll ???? To the header 
So we shall give `a` tag the target to the menu

```
<a href= "#menu-main"><span></span>Scroll</a>
```

that shall fix it